# Почему после особождения памяти функцией free указатель не становится равным NULL?

Tags: c++, указатели

Хотел проверить, реально ли освободилась память, а оказалось, что не совсем...

Почему выполняется последнее условие и выводится: «Not empty»?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    int len;

    cout << "Enter size of string: ";
    cin >> len;

    char * buffer = (char*) malloc(len);          // выделение памяти

    if (buffer == NULL) exit (1);                 // проверка, если выделение памяти не произошло, завершить 

    for (int ix = 0; ix < len; ix++)
        buffer[ix] = rand() % 26 + 'a';

    cout << "Random string: " << buffer <<endl;;
    free(buffer);                                  // освобождение памяти 

    if (buffer != NULL)
        cout << "Not empty" << endl;               // !

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что `free` не меняет значение переменной `buffer`. Кроме того, не следует мешать C и С++

Comment: он освобождает память? нет?

Comment: Да, блок памяти, на который указывает указатель `buffer`, будет освобожден. После возврата функции значение указателя остается неизменным, но теперь уже не является валидным, то бишь указатель по-прежнему указывает на тот же (теперь уже освобожденный) блок.

Comment: Потому что С делался с расчетом в первую очередь на скорость, а не на удобство. На зануление тратилось бы лишнее время, даже когда это зануление не нужно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`free` освобождает память, но ничего не делает с указателем - да и не может делать, потому что он передается не по ссылке, а по значению.

Поэтому ваша проверка ничего не даст - `buf` остается тем же.

Поскольку `free()` ничего не возвращает, вы не можете проверить успешность освобождения. Если вы передали верный указатель, полученный от `malloc` и освобождаете ее первый и единственный раз - все будет хорошо :)

Answer (score 2):

Функция `free` - это просто функция, получающая свой аргумент по значению. Она не может ничего "выставлять" - у нее нет никакого доступа к оригинальному аргументу. Более того, операнд функции освобождения памяти не обязан являться lvalue, поэтому никакого речи об "установке его в null" идти не может в принципе.

Никто вам не запрещает делать так

```
char *ptr = (char *) malloc(1024) + 1024;
...
free(ptr - 1024);
```

Что вы собрались "выставлять в null" в этом случае?

Это еще от оператора `delete` можно было ожидать "выставления указателя в null" (раз уж ваш вопрос помечен как [С++]), а от функции `free` такого ожидать не приходится.

Формально указатель, указывающий на освобожденную память, имеет invalid pointer value. Что произойдет при попытке анализа значения такого указателя определяется реализацией.